# Nginx page speed writes to http instead of relative urls serving behind load balancer

Tags: https, nginx, google-pagespeed

I have a problem with Google's 'nginx page speed' plugin which writes the urls to http://example.com. I am using Elastic Load Balancer to map https to http on AWS.

I am finding the modified urls as http://example.com/sample.XXXXXXX.css. This works fine on http end points, but when I have https end point, the css is not working because of security/cross domain from http to https change.

Is there a way to make the page speed module to use relative urls instead of absolute ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the nginx config to use X-Forwarded-Proto via `pagespeed RespectXForwardedProto on;`

Source: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/https_support